# JPA Transient property together Hibernate Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, transient

Is there possible to use `@PostLoad` with Hibernate Criteria API? For instance:

```
@Entity
public class EntityExample {

  private Integer startYear;

  private Integer startPeriod;

  @Transient
  private String start;

  @PostLoad
  private void init() {
    this.start = this.startYear.toString() + this.startPeriod.toString();
  }

  public String getStart() {
    return this.start;
  }
}
```

---

```
public class DAOExample {

  public Collection<EntityExample> get(String start) {
    Session session = getSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(EntityExample.class, "entity");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("entity.start", start));
    return criteria.list();
  }
}
```

---

When I use `@Formula` with Hibernate Criteria (for example: `@Formula(value = "start_year::text || start_period::text")`), it works fine. But I'm trying to use `@PostLoad` 'cause if it's needed refactor any envolved property it will not be necessary remember change manually the `value` of the formula. However, using `@PostLoad` causes: `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: start of: com.entity.EntityExample`

Answer (score 0):

`@Transient` marks properties as not included in the database table. Now you use `Criteria API` to create a query containing it. This equals following query:

```
select * from EntityExample where start != 'start value'
```

This one will fail as well, because `start` is no column in that table. You will need to do workaound for this. Without knowing the use case it is very much impossible to think of a good workaround. The easiest one would be to just include `start` in the table, but I guess you had reasons to not include it right away